# Adding gradient to element breaks CSS functionality in IE

Tags: css

I am working on a CSS-based drop-down menu. It works fine until I add gradient to elements. Than something breaks in IE and when I hover over `<li>` items in sub-menu the menu box disappears.

Here's the code I use to add gradient and make it cross-browser compatible:

```
background-color: #c1ddf4; /* for non-css3 browsers */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#c1ddf4', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #c1ddf4), color-stop(100%, #ffffff));/* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c1ddf4, #ffffff); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#c1ddf4, #ffffff);
```

Please see the following examples:

[**OK** *(without gradient)*](http://jsfiddle.net/DqTyh/8/) vs. [**NOT OK** *(with gradient)*](http://jsfiddle.net/DqTyh/9/)

Comment: hope http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ will help you getting CBC gradient

Comment: this is cool! However, i am still dealing with the same issue that affects the menu. I think it has to do with the filter:

Answer (score 1):

The IE filter *will* break certain functionality when applied to elements. My suggestion is to use a horizontally tiled gradient image for IE, either by using a CSS hack, an IE-only style sheet, or targeting it using [Modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/).

The truly proper way would be to use Modernizr, then write this CSS:

```
.no-cssgradients li {
     background: url(gradient.png) repeat-y;
}
```

That way, any browser that doesn't support CSS gradients (not just IE) will get served the image instead.

Comment: Yes, it was definitely "filter". What I did is wrapped the element with another div and moved the gradient there. Thanks.