# IE9: Issues with anchor tag sizing and li hover

Tags: html, css, navigation, internet-explorer-9, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a navigation bar - using usual stuff. It works as expected in Firefox and Chrome, but does not in IE9. Apparently there are two problems:

1. The anchor tag for the top level does not fill the containing li. I
   have used display:block, height: 100% and width:100% as you will see
   in the code.
2. The hover for the top level items does not bring out
   the lower level items. The hover changes the font and background
   though.

There are numerous articles and forum posts on these two topics - I hope I have understood and already implemented the solutions discussed. But perhaps I am missing something simple.

The css file: dropdown-menu.css

```
#navigation-ul {

padding: 0;

margin: 0;

list-style: none;

height: 35px; /* this height must match the #navigation-ul li.top height */ 

position: relative;

z-index: 200;

font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;

}



#navigation-ul li.top {

display: block;

float: left;

height: 35px;

width: 150px;



/* This was the original size

height: 30px;

width: 100px;

*/



background-color: #E1E1E3;

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#FFFFFF",

    endColorstr="#C4C4C4" ); /* for IE */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFFFFF),

    to(#C4C4C4) ); /* for webkit browsers */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #C4C4C4);

/* for firefox 3.6+ */

border-right: 4px groove #D1D1D1;

}



#navigation-ul li a.top_link {

display: block;

float: left;

height: 100%;

width: 100%; 

line-height : 33px;

color: #003570;

text-decoration: none;

font-size: 14px;

font-weight: bold;

padding: 0;

cursor: pointer;

text-align: center;

line-height: 33px;

}



#navigation-ul li a.top_link span {

color: #003570;

font-size: 14px;

float: left;

display: block;

padding: 0;

height: 100%;

width: 100%;

}



#navigation-ul li a.top_link span.down {

color: #003570;

font-size: 14px;

float: left;

display: block;

padding: 0;

height: 100%;

width: 100%;

}



#navigation-ul li:hover a.top_link {

height: 100%;

color: #FF0000;

text-decoration: underline;

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#C4C4C4",

    endColorstr="#FFFFFF" ); /* for IE */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#C4C4C4),

    to(#FFFFFF) ); /* for webkit browsers */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C4C4C4, #FFFFFF);

/* for firefox 3.6+ */

}



#navigation-ul li:hover a.top_link span {

height: 150%;

color: #FF0000;

text-decoration: underline;

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#C4C4C4",

    endColorstr="#FFFFFF" ); /* for IE */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#C4C4C4),

    to(#FFFFFF) ); /* for webkit browsers */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C4C4C4, #FFFFFF);

/* for firefox 3.6+ */

}



#navigation-ul li:hover a.top_link span.down {

height: 150%;

color: #FF0000;

text-decoration: underline;

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#C4C4C4",

    endColorstr="#FFFFFF" ); /* for IE */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#C4C4C4),

    to(#FFFFFF) ); /* for webkit browsers */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C4C4C4, #FFFFFF);

/* for firefox 3.6+ */

}











/* Default list styling */

#navigation-ul li:hover {

position: relative;

z-index: 200;

}



#navigation-ul li:hover ul.sub {

left: 0px;

top: 50px; /* (top level li height is YYpx) + (xx% of that (= 0.xx*YY px) height increase on hover) */

padding: 0;

white-space: nowrap;

width: 200px;

height: auto;

z-index: 300;

}



#navigation-ul li:hover ul.sub li {

display: block;

height: 30px;

border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;



background-color: #E1E1E3; 

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#C4C4C4",

    endColorstr="#FFFFFF" ); /* for IE */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#C4C4C4),

    to(#FFFFFF) ); /* for webkit browsers */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C4C4C4, #FFFFFF);



position: relative;

float: left;

width: 200px;

font-weight: normal;

}



#navigation-ul li:hover ul.sub li a {

display: block;

font-size: 12px;

height: 100%;

width: 100%;

line-height: 18px;

text-indent: 5px;

color: #003570;

text-decoration: none;

}



#navigation-ul li ul.sub li a.fly {

/* background: #bbd37e url(arrow.gif) 80px 6px no-repeat; */



}



#navigation-ul li:hover ul.sub li a:hover {

color: #FF0000;

font-weight: bold;

text-decoration: underline;

}



/* Hover effect over the 2nd level li*/

#navigation-ul li:hover ul.sub li a.fly:hover {

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#FFFFFF",

    endColorstr="#C4C4C4" ); /* for IE */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#FFFFFF),

    to(#C4C4C4) ); /* for webkit browsers */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #C4C4C4);



color: #FF000;

font-weight: bold;

width: 105%;

border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;

text-decoration: underline;

}



#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover ul,#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover li:hover ul,#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover ul,#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover ul

{

left: 210px; /* (higher level li width is 200px) + 5% (=10px) increase during hover */

top: 0px;

background: #C4C4C4;

padding: 0px;

margin-bottom: 1px;

white-space: nowrap;

/* width: 150px; */

z-index: 400;

height: auto;

}



#navigation-ul ul,#navigation-ul li:hover ul ul,#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover ul ul,#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover li:hover ul ul,#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover ul ul

{

position: absolute;

left: -9999px;

top: -9999px;

width: 0;

height: 0;

margin: 0;

padding: 0;

list-style: none;

}



/* Hover effect over the 2nd level li - going from 2nd level to 3rd level*/

#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover a.fly,#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly,#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly,#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly

{

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#FFFFFF",

    endColorstr="#C4C4C4" ); /* for IE */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#FFFFFF),

    to(#C4C4C4) ); /* for webkit browsers */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #C4C4C4);



color: #FF000;

font-weight: bold;

width: 105%;

border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;

text-decoration: underline;

}



#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover li a.fly,#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li a.fly,#navigation-ul li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li a.fly

{

background: #bbd37e url(arrow.gif) 80px 6px no-repeat;

color: #000;

border-color: #bbd37e;

}
```

The javascript file: dropdown-menu.js

```
SampleHover = function() {



var cssRule;



var newSelector;



for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {



    for (var j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[i].rules.length ; j++) {



        cssRule = document.styleSheets[i].rules[j];



        if (cssRule.selectorText.indexOf("li:hover") != -1) {



            newSelector = cssRule.selectorText.replace(/li:hover/gi, "li.hover");

            document.styleSheets[i].addRule(newSelector , cssRule.style.cssText);

        }

    }

}



var liElements = document.getElementById("navigation-ul").getElementsByTagName("li");



for ( var i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++ ) {



    liElements[i].onmouseover = function() {



        this.className = this.className + " hover";

    };



    liElements[i].onmouseout = function() {



        this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp(" hover\\b"), "");

    };

}

};



if (window.attachEvent) {



window.attachEvent("onload", SampleHover); 

}
```

The html file: sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>

<title>Sample</title>
<meta name="description" content=""></meta>
<meta name="keywords" content=""></meta>
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow"></meta>



<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"></meta>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="sample.css"
    type="text/css" title="Sample Style" media="screen, print"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown-menu.css"
    type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="dropdown-menu.js"></script>

</head>




<body style="align: CENTER;">

<div id=main style="width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;">

    <div id=header>

<div id="navigation-div" style="padding-bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">

<!--  <span class="preload1"></span> <span class="preload2"></span> -->

<ul id="navigation-ul"
    style="display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #D1D1D1; margin-left: 0px; border-radius: 5px;">
    <li class="top" style="border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;"><a
        class="top_link" href="/index">Home</a></li>


    <li class="top"><a id="Solutions" class="top_link down"
        href="/solutions"><span class="down">Solutions</span></a>
        <ul class="sub">

            <li><a class="fly" href="/solutions/business">Business
                    Solutions</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/solutions/business/investment-decision">Investment
                            Decisions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/solutions/business/product-mgmt">Product
                            Management</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a class="fly" href="/solutions/software">Software
                    Solutions</a></li>

            <li><a class="fly" href="/solutions/engineering">Engineering
                    Solutions</a></li>
        </ul></li>


    <li class="top" ><a
        id="Industries" class="top_link" href="/industries"><span
            class="down">Industries</span></a></li>

    <li class="top" ><a
        id="KnowledgeBase" class="top_link" href="/knowledgebase"><span
            class="down">KnowledgeBase</span></a></li>

    <li class="top" style="border: none; width: 342px; border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;"></li>

</ul>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you keep the three files in the same directory, you should be able to reproduce what I am seeing. Thank you for your help.

Prajesh

Comment: Stackoverflow rocks! When I visit my question, I get all the related threads on the right side. I checked out this one: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226159/drop-down-menu-doesnt-work-in-ie9). It talks about using ms-filter instead of just filter to accomplish gradient background. It has fixed both problems, but it turned out there was a third problem that was hidden in there. On hover, I want the height of the top links to become 150% and the submenu items start after that. IE starts the submenu at the correct z-index, but does not increase the height of the top menu item.

Comment: I just noticed, the gradient actually vanished with the addition of the ms- prefix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very last line in this post [Adding gradient to element breaks CSS functionality in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418680/adding-gradient-to-element-breaks-css-functionality-in-ie) did the trick! Following are a few noteworthy observations for people that might face similar problem in the future.

1. Of course, the IE filter gradient does not go very well with the ul
   or li - meaning if the gradient is applied to an li the li gets the
   gradient, but all its sub-items become hidden (or does not appear on
   hover over the top level li).
2. However, if the filter is applied on
   an element internal to the li (for example a div inside the li),
   then both the gradient and the drop-down work.
3. In my case, I wanted my top level li to increase in height on hover and have the sub-ul
       top start below where the top li ends. Since the filter was not
       working initially, the li was not getting filled with any background
       and hence there was a gap between the top level li and the sub-ul. I
       should have followed the best practice of having a default flat
       background, in case the filter did not work. When I did that with
       the filter commented out, the dropdown worked fine (no discontinuity
       between the top level li and the sub-ul).
4. The suggestion I followed initially and was happy about [Drop down menu doesn't work in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226159/drop-down-menu-doesnt-work-in-ie9) turned out to be a no-solution. Adding ms- or -ms or anything for that matter in front of filter essentially just comments out the filter line.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code under `<head>` tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Like this

```
<html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
        <!-- Your codes / styles / scripts -->
       </head>
       <body>
         <!-- your codes-->
       </body>
</html>
```